# vb.net DataGridView Uncommitted new row cannot be made invisible

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I have a DataGridView in my VB.net Form. I need to make some rows invisible based on a value. As there is not GridviewrowdataBound, I am trying to achieve it as shown in the below Code

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellFormatting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellFormatting

        If DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("ApplicationIDPKDataGridViewTextBoxColumn").Value <> "1" Then
            DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Visible = False
        End If

    End Sub
```

When I try to do this I am getting the Uncommitted new row cannot be made visible error.

Any thoughts??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you allow users to add new items to the DataGridView? If it's the case, maybe the row used to add a new item cannot be made invisible...

Answer (score 3):

This is the code that helped me

```
dgridView.CurrentCell = null;
dgridView.Rows[i].Visible = false;
```

[Code from Here](http://codeasp.net/blogs/vivek_iit/microsoft-net/185/row-associated-with-the-currency-managers-position-cannot-be-made-invisible)

Answer (score 1):

dgridView.AllowUserToAddRows = false;

Then try again